# Session cookie lost when switching apps on Android

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies

We have a website which uses session cookies for authentication.

We have seen, in certain situation (unable to pin down the magic formula), that if after logging in (where the session cookie is set), the user uses the website for a while and then switches apps just to later switch back to the web app again, the user will be required to log in again.

It seems at this last point the user loses their session cookie.

The web app is entirely browser based - not a native app, just a website.

This issue can present itself over just a period of a couple of minutes where the user will lose their session. All the while, another user may not experience this at all.

I'm speculating here... but is there some aspect of Android that kills background apps or perhaps shuts them down if there is memory pressure when they're not active?

This constant requirement of our users to re-login is very interruptive to the flow that we expect them to take.

This issue does not happen on iOS.

Comment: When a browser is backgrounded, it can be killed for resources.  In that case, session cookies can be lost (and probably are, since they should only be stored in RAM).  The solution is to not use a session cookie, or to live with it.

Comment: To better reproduce the problem, enable developer settings on android and set "background process limit" to 0 in the developer settings. This will force the behaviour. So you can switch apps, wait a few seconds just to be safe and then switch back.